# HttpPost with Proxy

Tags: c#, http-post, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, networkstream

I'm using HttpPost with proxy in my code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; });
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls |  SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 |  SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri)
request.Proxy = GetProxy();
request.Method = method.ToString().ToUpper();
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.151 Safari/535.19";
request.Accept = "image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-silverlight, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-silverlight-2-b2, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control: no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: zh-cn");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

When I run `request.GetResponse`, the system throw error as:

```
[System.IO.IOException] = {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
```

The proxy is valid and I can use the proxy in Web Browser.

Comment: Why are you blindly accepting any and all SSL certificates? If this is production code, please don't do this. If they are self-signed cerificates, you can still write your own code to validate the, rather than just accepting any.

Comment: I found some of the solution solve this problem by added the SSL cert.
Actually, this code just fail to work in my pc, i'm not sure is it the Visual studio or my network problem, by right its should not be the network problem, because i can pass thru the proxy on web browser.